# Jquery Ajax throw error before ActionResult return

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, telerik, asp.net-mvc-4

I´m fighting a weird problem which is probably due to my inexperience with ajax.  For some reason my Ajax function fires my error alert dialog even before my ActionResult returns it PartialView.

Can any1 spot why my ajax function throws error, or even what I´m doing wrong?

**My Jquery**

```
function GetSalesLinesByArea(e) {
var areaId = treeView().getItemValue(e.item);
$('#HiddenAreaId').val(areaId);
var url = '/SalesLine/IndexPartial/';
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    url: url,
    data: { areaNodeId: areaId },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#HuntingGrid').html(data);
        alert("success!");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error!");
    }
  });
}
```

**My view Index.cshtml**

```
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI
@using Veidivefur.Model.Entity
@model Veidivefur.ViewModels.SalesLineViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Hlunnindi";
}

<div id="HuntingGrid">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("IndexPartial"); }
</div>
```

**My partialview IndexPartial.cshtml**

```
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI
@model Veidivefur.ViewModels.SalesLineViewModel

<div>
    @(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.SalesLines)
        .Name("Grid")
        //More Telerik stuff
</div>
```

**My Index ActionResult in Controller **

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<CombinedSalesLine> combinedSalesLines =
            GenerateSalesLines(_salesLineModel.FindAllSalesLinesLargerThanToday(0));

        return View(new SalesLineViewModel(combinedSalesLines));
    }
```

**My IndexPartial ActionResult in Controller **

```
    public ActionResult IndexPartial(string areaNodeId)
    {
        int areaNodeInt = Convert.ToInt32(areaNodeId);

        List<SalesLine> saleslines = areaNodeInt == 0 ? _salesLineModel.FindAllSalesLinesLargerThanToday(0)
            : _salesLineModel.FindAllSalesLinesLargerThanToday(areaNodeInt);

        List<CombinedSalesLine> combinedSalesLines = GenerateSalesLines(saleslines);

        return PartialView("IndexPartial", new SalesLineViewModel(combinedSalesLines));
    }
```

Comment: are you sure the url should be `/SalesLine/IndexPartial/`? with the slashes? and no .html .php or .asp page?

Comment: Hello @RASG, yes I´m pretty sure that´s how it´s done, at least I used this method in other projects before.  The problem is once the url has fired my ActionResult function my ajax function throws an error even before my ActionResult has returned anything..!?

Comment: Is it it hitting the server side code at all, or just returning an error?

Comment: @JeffreyLott, it is actually hitting the server side code.  Just before my server side code will return (in my IndexPartial) the ajax throws an error and the alert dialog pops up.  The strange thing is that as soon as I close the dialog window the server side code keeps running and actually returns the correct Model up to the View but for some reason the View doesn´t render the new data.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue!  The code I issued with my question seems to be correct.  The problem was with the way I call my ajax function, the url I was using also called another function and therefore the ajax function threw an error.  I feel very silly but happy it got resolved.